# Produce Data in JSON

Tags: java, jersey

Need your help. 
I am using postman and trying to get information in JSON format.
But instead of correct format of message i got this result -> "[]"

I don't have any error and i can print in console the requested information, but can't in the browser. I hope anybody can give me a clue..

```
@GET
@Path("/{messager_id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String GetMessageById(@PathParam("messager_id") long id){

    String message = new MessageService().getMessageById(id);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: your message contains data ?

Comment: Yes. Only the - > " [ ] " symbol!

Comment: Instead of : Name, Last Name, MessageDate ..

Comment: not in browser i mean in java ?

Comment: Sure. name , last name, message date and..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to first of all, use some webservice client as DHC REST Client (an addon for Chrome browser). Use it and check the real behaviour of your webservice. If the client gets and empty json object, then sure your server is producing empty data. Log the string `message` to be sure is returning data. If it is correct, check the return method. An example of returning of a webservice can be:

```
return Response.ok(message, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

Comment: If your MessageService() does not return the message already as a JSON (as I assume) you are expecting that by magic is converted as JSON structure. Your answer `hasEntity = false` has non sense to me, neither the edit you have tried to do on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the content type header is set : `Content-type = application/json`. Please provide additional information.

Comment: I do have Content-type = application/json.

Comment: The way the data is printed in the console. If you are using jersey rest then return the response as **Response.ok(message).build()** and change the return type to **javax.ws.rs.core.Response** instead of **String**.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check for is to ensure that the MessageService.getMessageById(id) is returning data.

Comment: I did it with system.out to console and got the message correct!

Comment: But not in JSON format in browser.. What can it be ?